Resolving the issue : Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" (type string) at path "_id" for model "products"
Error message:
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" (type string) at path "_id" for model "products".

I'm attempting to retrieve a product, but I keep encountering the above error.
productController.jsx
const formidable = require("formidable");
const { responseReturn } = require("./../../utiles/response");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
const productModel = require("./../../models/productModels");

class productController {
    add_product = async (req, res) => {
        const { id } = req;

        // Création d'une instance de formidable pour analyser les formulaires multipart
        const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

        // Analyse la requête entrante (req)
        form.parse(req, async (err, field, files) => {
            // console.log(files[0]);
            // console.log(files.images[0]);
            // console.log(files);
            // console.log(field);

            // Extraction des champs non fichiers depuis field
            let { name, category, brand, price, stock, discount, description, shopName } = field;

            // Extraction des fichiers depuis files
            const { images } = files;

            // Traitement du champ name pour créer un slug
            name = name.trim();
            const slug = name.split(" ").join("-");

            cloudinary.config({
                cloud_name: process.env.cloud_name,
                api_key: process.env.api_key,
                api_secret: process.env.api_secret,
                secure: true,
            });

            // On veut load notre multiple images
            try {
                let allImageUrl = [];
                for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
                    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(images[index].filepath, { folder: "products" });
                    // Le folder se cré dans le cloudinary.

                    // Cette ligne de code permet de push les images dans le tableau allImageUrl
                    allImageUrl = [...allImageUrl, result.url];
                }

                await productModel.create({
                    sellerId: id,
                    name,
                    slug,
                    shopName,
                    category: category.trim(),
                    description: description.trim(),
                    stock: parseInt(stock),
                    price: parseInt(price),
                    discount: parseInt(discount),
                    brand: brand.trim(),
                    images: allImageUrl,
                });

                responseReturn(res, 201, { message: "Product Added Successfully" });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error adding product:", error);
                responseReturn(res, 500, { error: "Internal Server Error" });
            }
        });
    };

    // End method

    products_get = async (req, res) => {
        const { page, searchValue, parPage } = req.query;
        const { id } = req;

        const skipPage = parseInt(parPage) * (parseInt(page) - 1);

        try {
            if (searchValue) {
                const products = await productModel
                    .find({
                        $text: { $search: searchValue },
                        sellerId: id,
                    })
                    .skip(skipPage)
                    .limit(parPage)
                    .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
                const totalProduct = await productModel
                    .find({
                        $text: { $search: searchValue },
                        sellerId: id,
                    })
                    .countDocuments();
                responseReturn(res, 200, { products, totalProduct });
            } else {
                const products = await productModel
                    .find({ sellerId: id })
                    .skip(skipPage)
                    .limit(parPage)
                    .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
                const totalProduct = await productModel.find({ sellerId: id }).countDocuments();
                responseReturn(res, 200, { products, totalProduct });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    // End method

    product_get = async (req, res) => {
        const { productId } = req.params;
        try {
            const product = await productModel.findById(productId);
            responseReturn(res, 200, { product });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    };
    // End Method
}

module.exports = new productController();


productRoutes.js
const productController = require("./../../controllers/dashboard/productController");
const { authMiddleware } = require("../../middlewares/authMiddleware");
const router = require("express").Router();

router.post("/product-add", authMiddleware, productController.add_product);
router.get("/products-get", authMiddleware, productController.products_get); // get all products
router.get("/product-get/:productId", authMiddleware, productController.product_get);

module.exports = router;

EditProduct.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { get_category } from "./../../store/Reducers/categoryReducer";
import { get_product } from "./../../store/Reducers/productReducer";

function EditProduct() {
    // productId vient du fichier routes/sellerRoutes.js
    const { productId } = useParams();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // Permet de récupérer les catégories dans notre state
    const { categories } = useSelector((state) => state.category);

    // on peut acceder à product car on l'a déclaré dans le fichier productReducer (product)
    const { product } = useSelector((state) => state.product);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(
            // get_category provient du fichier categoryReducer
            get_category({
                searchValue: "",
                parPage: "",
                page: "",
            })
        );
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(
            // get_category provient du fichier categoryReducer
            get_product({ productId })
        );
    }, [productId]);

    const [categoryShow, setCategoryShow] = useState(false);
    const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
    // const [allCategory, setAllCategory] = useState([]);
    const [allCategory, setAllCategory] = useState(categories);
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

    const aryane = "azertyuiopqsdfghjkMDFRxcvbn";
    const categorySearch = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        // on doit passer notre valeur dans le setsearchValue
        setSearchValue(value);
        // on doit filtrer les categories
        if (value) {
            let searchValue = allCategory.filter(
                (category) => category.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1
            );
            setAllCategory(searchValue);
        } else {
            setAllCategory(categories);
        }
    };

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: "",
        description: "",
        discount: "",
        price: "",
        brand: "",
        stock: "",
    });

    const inputHandle = (event) => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [imageShow, setImageShow] = useState([]);

    const changeImage = (img, files) => {
        if (files.length > 0) {
            console.log(files[0]);
            console.log(img);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setState({
            name: product.name,
            description: product.description,
            discount: product.discount,
            price: product.price,
            brand: product.brand,
            stock: product.stock,
        });
        setCategory(product.category);
        setImageShow(product.images);
    }, [product]);

And the code with the _id in Product.jsx
 <Link
 to={`/seller/dashboard/edit-product/${product._id}`}                                              className="p-[6px] bg-yellow-500 rounded hover:shadow-lg hover:shadow-yellow-500/50">{" "}
 <FaEdit />{" "}
 </Link>

This is my productReducer.js with my methods with getProduct where I use ProductId. With my extraReducer and Reducer.
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import api from "../../api/api";

export const get_product = createAsyncThunk(
    "product/get_product",
    async (productId, { rejectWithValue, fulfillWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await api.get(`/product-get/${productId}`, { withCredentials: true });
            console.log(data);
            return fulfillWithValue(data);
        } catch (error) {
            // console.log(error.response.data)
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// End Method

export const productReducer = createSlice({
    name: "product",
    initialState: {
        successMessage: "",
        errorMessage: "",
        loader: false,
        userInfo: "",
        products: [],
        product: "",
        totalProduct: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        messageClear: (state, _) => {
            state.errorMessage = "";
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(add_product.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.loader = true;
            })
            .addCase(add_product.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.loader = false;
                state.errorMessage = payload.error;
            })
            .addCase(add_product.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.loader = false;
                state.successMessage = payload.message;
            })
            .addCase(get_products.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.totalProduct = payload.totalProduct;
                state.products = payload.products;
            })
            .addCase(get_product.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.product = payload.product;
            });
    },
});

export const { messageClear } = productReducer.actions;
export default productReducer.reducer;



Can you provide the definition for 'get_product' reducer from 'productReducer' ?

@MohsinMurad Hello, do you mean the Reducer ? I am going to add it to the code

You've a typo, passing productId in an object with get_product({ productId }) but passing the entire object in the URL request instead of just the id value async (productId, ...) => { and api.get(`/product-get/${productId}`,...);. Either use get_product(productId) when dispatching or destructure the payload value async ({ productId }, ...) => {. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

It seems when your react component EditProduct.jsx is loading, in the useEffect you are dispatching a reducer to get the product by id. There is a minor mistake with your dispatch syntax.
Reason
According to the get_product reducer definition, the reducer method is expecting a productId as string and is passing the parameter as it is to the API call. Whereas, in the useEffect of your component you are passing an object to the dispatched reducer.
Fix
There are two possible ways to fix:

You can change the dispatch call in your EditProduct.jsx as follows:
 /*Existing code */

 useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(
         // get_category provient du fichier categoryReducer
         get_product(productId);
     );
 }, [productId]);
// Remaining Existing code


OR You can change the API call in the get_product reducer definition, in your productReducer as follows:
/* Existing code */

export const get_product = createAsyncThunk(
    "product/get_product",
     async (productId, { rejectWithValue, fulfillWithValue }) => {
         try {
             const { data } = await api.get(`/product-get/${productId.productId}`,
                                         {withCredentials: true });
             console.log(data);
             return fulfillWithValue(data);
          } catch (error) {
             // console.log(error.response.data)
             return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
         }
     }
 );

 /* Remaining existing code */



Remeber
Only use One of above solution to get the API call correct.
